# Nginx Issue with stream and upstream to VMware UAG

Tags: nginx, load-balance

I'm trying to setup VMware UAG load balanced with Nginx. I keep getting this error,

`nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here.`

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am in no way a developer so please excuse my ignorance.
Thanks in advance Here's my config:

```
stream {
    upstream vdi_ssl {
        hash $remote_addr;
        server uag-01.example.com:443;
        server uag-02.example.com:443 down;
    }

    upstream vdi_pcoip {
        hash $remote_addr;
        server uag-01.example.com:4172;
        server uag-02.example.com:4172 down;
    }

    server {
        listen 10.4.44.2:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/*.pem;

        proxy_pass vdi_ssl;
        proxy_ssl on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/*.pem;
        proxy_timeout 20m;

        health_check;
    }

    server {
        listen 10.4.44.2:4172;

        proxy_pass vdi_pcoip;
        proxy_timeout 20m;

        health_check port=443;
    }

    server {
        listen 10.4.44.2:4172 udp;

        proxy_pass vdi_pcoip;
        proxy_timeout 20m;
    }
}

#HTTP Block
# To Load Balancer on Outside IP
server {
    if ($host = loadbalancer.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name loadbalancer.example.com;

    #set client body size to 10m#
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    # Don't allow pages to be rendered in an iframe on external domains.
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    # MIME sniffing prevention
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    # Enable cross-site scripting filter in supported browsers.
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block";
    # Prevent access to hidden files
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }
    # Prevent access to certain file extensions
    location ~\.(ini|log|conf)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; server_name loadbalancer.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/loadbalancer.example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/loadbalancer.example.com/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://loadbalancer.example.com:443; #My Horizon UAG
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_buffers 32 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/loadbalancer.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/loadbalancer.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have placed your `stream` block inside the `http` block. The `stream` block is a [top-level block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) like `http` and needs to be placed at the same level. This may require you to edit the main Nginx configuration file from which all other configuration files are included (using the `include` directive). The main configuration file is called something like `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you give me an example where I should place it in my config? include /etc/nginx/nginx.conf;

Comment: what is the distribution of the device?